# Molecular orbital diagrams for cojugated pi systems

Tags: chemistry, modiagram

I'm writing a paper about pericyclic reactions and I haven't found a good way to represent the energy levels of molecular orbitals of conjugated pi bonds. I've tried using the modiagram package, but it's very restricting and doesn't allow such images. As an example of what I'm interested in (excuse my bad handwriting, it's a quick sketch):
[image: Molecular orbitals of a triene]

Is there any way to draw such diagrams in LaTeX?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{modiagram}[names]
 \AO(20pt){p}{0;up ,up,up}
 \AO(80pt){s}{0;up}
 \AO(100pt){s}{0;up}
 \AO(120pt){s}{0;up}
 \AO(150pt){s}{-3;pair}
 \AO(150pt){s}{-2;pair}
\AO(150pt){s}{-1;pair}
\AO(150pt){s}{1;} 
\AO(150pt){s}{2;}
\AO(150pt){s}{3;}
\connect{ AO4 & AO5, AO4 & AO6, AO4 & AO7, AO4 & AO8, AO4 & AO9, AO4 & AO10 }
\node[right,xshift=4mm] at (AO7) {\footnotesize HOMO};
\node[right,xshift=4mm] at (AO8) {\footnotesize LUMO};
\EnergyAxis[title=Energy]
\end{modiagram}
\caption*{Molecular orbital diagram for a triene}
\end{figure}
```

Produces the following output:

[image: Triene MO diagram]

I still have yet to find a way to mark the light irritation and to make the diagram a little bigger, but it's a nice place to start.

Comment: Probably adding something like  `\AO(250pt){s}{-3;pair}
 \AO(250pt){s}{-2;pair}
 \AO(250pt){s}{-1;up}
 \AO(250pt){s}{1;up} 
 \AO(250pt){s}{2;}
 \AO(250pt){s}{3;}
 \node[right,xshift=4mm] at (AO14) {\footnotesize HOMO};
 \node[right,xshift=4mm] at (AO15) {\footnotesize LUMO};
 \node[right,xshift=-1mm, yshift=1mm] at (AO14) {*};
 \phantom{\AO(190pt){s}{0;}}
 \phantom{\AO(240pt){s}{0;}}
 \draw [->] (AO17) -- node [midway,above] {$h \nu$} (AO18);` helps to finish the diagram.